# Did I interprete 想像がつきません correctly here?

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a conversation with my language partner.

For some context:
「有頂天家族」を観たのですね。私も観ましたよ。タヌキ鍋ですよね。タヌキを愛しているから食べるって、不思議な表現です。愛しているけれど、決して自分のものにはならないから、自分の中に取り込んでしまう意味なのだろうかと考えました。
タヌキ鍋というのは、昔話にはでてきますが、現代の日本では食べないので、どんな味がするのか想像がつきません。

The sentence in question:
タヌキ鍋というのは、昔話にはでてきますが、現代の日本では食べないので、どんな味がするのか想像がつきません。

My attempt at translation:
"Concerning Tanuki-Hot-Pot, no imagination comes of what it tastes like because one doesn't eat it in present japan, although it appears in old tales."

Besides my question wether I interpreted 想像がつきません correctly or not, is there a reason why つきません is written without kanji? Or is it just a typo?
Also, I just assumed that でてきます is a typo and is meant to be できます. Am I correct there?

Comment: For the last question, it’s 出て来ます written in hiragana. You translated it correctly as “appears”; why did you assume it might be できます?

Answer (score 4):

Your translation is correct. 想像がつく is a set phrase ([Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%83%B3%E5%83%8F%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F)) meaning "one can imagine" (or substitute another subject for "one" as appropriate).

I would translate as follows:

> As for tanuki hot pot, while it's mentioned in folktales, it's not eaten in modern Japan, so I can't even imagine what it tastes like.

Finally, でてきます is 出て来ます written in hiragana. Generally speaking, it's more common to see words and phrases that *can* be written in kanji written in kana than Japanese learners might expect. 付く is one of those cases; it's probably more often seen in kana than kanji. e.g., try typing 気をつける into your IME and see what it suggests.